# How does one access state of a context in a navbar for a page component that the context is encapsulating?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Using API COntext and Hooks to create a shopping cart, you'd simply just have a component with a context wrapped around it which you can dispatch actions to add and remove products from the basket.

e.g.

```
<ShoppingBasketContext.Provider value={useReducer(shoppingBasketActions, shoppingBasketInitialState)}>
{children}
</ShoppingBasket.Provider>
```

Easy. Let's say you then have a component that is your ShoppingBasket which is what the provider is encapsulating and utlimately a page that the user see's when they click on the shopping basket icon. You can then retrieve the items in the basket by accessing the state. However, if you have a count of the items in your basket next to the shopping basket icon on your navbar, would you have to use a global state to get access to the shopping basket state?

I'm failing to understand a second solution without using global state.

Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume

```
const shoppingBasketInitialState = []

function shoppingBasketActions(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_ITEM':
      return [...state, action.item]
    case 'REMOVE_ITEM':
      return state.filter(item => item.id !== action.item.id)
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}
```

Then you can access your items count like this:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [items] = useContext(ShoppingBasketContext)
  console.log(items.length) // logs items count
}
```

No need for global state.

Comment: Yes, that's right, from my understanding, you can only do this if the "SomeComponent" is a child of the ShoppingBasket Context. This will work fine for the Shopping Basket page, however, if you have an icon in the navbar that shows a count of the items in the basket (that will be outside of the context) how would you access the state then? The problem is, you can't wrap the shopping basket context around the navbar and the router as you'll be giving a page opportunity to access the context when it doesn't need to, and if the count updates, it'll cause a re-render of the router unnecessarily